# MAC with Parallels windows support on visual studio

Tags: c#, windows, macos, visual-studio, parallels

I'm a student in informatics. I've just bought the brand new MacBook M2 pro. I was hyped and wanted to start programming with a good laptop. Before the school started at the info day they told us to just have a laptop they didn't precise the OS. so instead windows I just bought MAC. Yesterday while we started with the first fundamentals the teacher said " People with MAC from now next week you'll have problems cause we'll start using Visual Studio and not more Visual Studio Code. We'll learn C# and you'll have too much issues. He simply said if you wanna follow the courses u need a windows pc and not mac.

Another guy in my classroom had a MAC too they couldn't manage to download Visual Studio and to  install. I wanted to give a try aswell and it worked but I saw the official announcement for their retirement on 31 august 2024. After that I did a lot of researches how to solve this problem and I found Parallels which you can virtualize your computer and install very simply windows on there. So here comes my question after my installations on parallels if I install the windows on my mac. Will I be exactly same as a normal windows computer with the same functionalities on visual studio or will it never be same as an original windows computer.

Cause I remember the teacher after I told him I have succesfull visual studio. He answered me : " What processor do you have on your mac ? " I say M2 he said it needs to be intel. I'm so confused. Couldn't an M2 Pro processor help with windows OS on mac with parallels ? P.S: Don't say to tell this to the teacher he doesn't care and doesn't answer at all any MAC related stuffs.

I didn't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of programs you're aiming to write plays a role here. Generally, both ARM and Intel processors should handle most tasks. But there are differences, not just in architecture but in features too. For instance, if you dive into intricate vector calculations, the ARM might feel a bit limited. There could be other features that might not be fully supported. But since you're just starting with your courses (first semester, right?), you likely won't hit those limits soon.

Both Windows and macOS have their emulation layers. Speaking of macOS, it uses "Rosetta 2" for emulation. Rosetta 2 is a translation process that enables a Mac with Apple silicon to use apps built for a Mac with an Intel processor. It ensures smooth app compatibility on the new architecture.

Parallels can assist you in running Visual Studio in your desired version, and most programs should run seamlessly. Give it a whirl! And if you ever feel you're pushing the boundaries, don't hesitate to reach out here or to me directly. We're here to help!

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer and I really feel better now 

Just the little confusing part -> "There could be other features that might not be fully supported. " Is this for Visual Studio or the vector calculations.

Comment: It has more to do with advanced features of intel processors (for example, advanced vector calculations) than with Visual Studio itself.